# What are the data validation when upload data

Tags: validation, data

Wanted to see if anyone knows what rules ET use to validate email address when it imports?

Comment: what do you mean 'what rules ET use'? i believe it should be valid email id. It Means should contain @ . and end with valid domin i.e .com , .org etc

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but I think it more than checking there's a @ and .com/.org etc in the email address that's why I'm asking to see if anyone knows As I am loosing customer when loading data in to a DE the error log is showing invalid email address. Is there a list where I can find the rules?